# CMPedometer is not running

Tags: cocoa, core-motion

My CMPedometer is not running.

The code before it and after it gets run, but it itself does not work.
I get no warning or exception.
I'm testing it on a real 5s.

I've tried both querydata and startpedometerupdates.

I am importing core motion and the library is linked.

Any help?

```
if ([CMPedometer isStepCountingAvailable] == YES)
    {
    CMPedometer *cmped;
    [cmped queryPedometerDataFromDate:start toDate:[NSDate date] withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error){
        stepslabel.text = [pedometerData.numberOfSteps stringValue];
    }];

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems really odd but I got it working by not declaring in the .h or before using it. What worked was declaring as @property CMPedometer *cmped; right after interface

Comment: For me [CMPedometer isStepCountingAvailable] is returning "NO". I am testing it in iPhone 5s, 5c and 4s but not working with any devices. plz tell how can I implement foot step count using CMPedometer or is there any other way for it??

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the original code above is the `cmped` variable gets deallocated at the end of the if statement, so the query is destroyed before it finishes.
By changing it to a `strong` property, it is retained in memory for the life of the class.